# Statistical estimators distance for close empirical distributions

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, inference, kullback-leibler, wasserstein

Is it valid to argue that two empirical distributions $ p_1, p_2 $ having small Wasserstein distance $W_r(\cdot)$ for an order $ r $ will yield close MLE estimators for a statistical model parameterized by a vector $\theta$, i.e. $ W_r(p_1, p_2) \approx 0 $ implies $ ||\theta_1^{\text{MLE}} - \theta_2^{\text{MLE}}|| \approx 0 $ for some norm $||\cdot||$ (under assumptions for the likelihood function, e.g. smoothness)? Is there some other closeness guarantee for inference on distributions close in Wasserstein distance or some other statistical divergence, e.g. Kullback-Leibler divergence, that we can claim for point estimates, e.g. MLE or MAP?